# Topology of derived sets and subset

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

if A is a subset of C ,then A' is a subset of  C' 
A' denotes set of all limits points of A

Comment: What that are asking you to prove is that if $x$ is a limit point of $C$ then it is also a limit point of $A$.  Can you do that by the definition of limit point?  If every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point $y\in A\subset C$ then $y \in C$ so........

Answer (score 3):

This is simply a matter of definitions.

$A \subset C$ means for every $x \in A$ then it is also true that $x\in C$.

And every $x \in A'$ is a limit point of $A$.

A limit point means that every neighborhood of $x$ contains a point $y; y\ne x$ so that $y \in A$.

But $A \subset C$ so $y \in C$.

So every neighbor hood of any $x \in A'$ contains a point $y; y \ne x$ so that $y  \in C$.

So any $x\in A'$ is a limit point of $C$.

So for any $x \in A'$ it is also true that $x\in C'$ and $A' \subset C'$.

There was nothing actually to prove.  It was just a matter of stating and understand what definitions mean.